# Using my own library : implicit declaration of function

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, shared-libraries, multi-project

Firstly, I'd like to thanks you in advance for the time you'll take to help me out. If I may suggest you, you can try reproduce my problem. Don't try to read the makefiles if you don't feel it'll help you to understand my problem.

*Also, I'd like to point out the fact I did a lot of researches and I don't have find any solution.*

## My Environment

---

- **Eclipse (with CDT)**
- **Windows (cygwin)** (but I also tried on Ubuntu)

I want to use my own (shared) library in a project.

## My Setup

---

### My Shared Library

**mylib.h**

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H_
#define MYLIB_H_

extern int foo();

#endif /* MYLIB_H_ */
```

**mylib.c**

```
#include "mylib.h"

extern int foo() {
    return 1;
}
```

### My Project

I added my library as a reference :

> Project Properties - C/C   Generals - Paths and Symbols - References (tab) - Check off mylib (Active)

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return foo();
}
```

### Problem

---

I'm getting ***implicit declaration of function 'foo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]*** warning when I build my project. **This warning only occurs** when I build my project while my library project has nothing to build (because it hasn't been modified since the last build).

**Console output**

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -std=c99 "-ID:\\Users\\cmourgeo\\maximo workspace\\mylib" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\uselib.o" "..\\src\\uselib.c" 
..\src\uselib.c: In function 'main':
..\src\uselib.c:12:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'foo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  return foo();
  ^
gcc "-LD:\\Users\\cmourgeo\\maximo workspace\\mylib\\Debug" -o uselib.exe "src\\uselib.o" -lmylib
```

Should I provide eclipse my own makefiles ? (under C/C++ / Builder Settings)

### Solution

---

I had to include my header in foo.c

```
#include "../src/mylib.h"
```

The path is kind of weird because of my projects structures :

- myproject

  - src

    - foo.c
- mylib

  - src

    - mylib.c
    - mylib.h

Thanks to user590028 for helping me getting through that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In foo.c you forgot to include the mylib.h header

```
/* foo.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mylib.h"  /* <-- include this line */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return foo();
}
```

Comment: I try to but it gives me "no such file or directory" error. I took a screenshot of my projects (I switched back on Ubuntu) : http://i.imgur.com/qxYvEIy.png.

Comment: Your compiler can't find the header file. Check the path you've specified to `gcc`. Make sure you have a line that include the path to where `mylib.h` lives.  For example `gcc -I/path/to/includes  foo.c`

Comment: It looks like it's ok but I take a screenshot of the build : http://i.imgur.com/ckK4iUF.png. Actually, the include path refers to the projet folder but not the one where the binaries are built. I'm gonna try to change de makefile. Your help is much appreciate, thanks !

Comment: I modified the path to be -I"/home/*****/workspace/mylib/Debug" instead of -I"/home/*****/workspace/mylib" but it still gives me the error.

Comment: Try this -- copy the include file into the same folder as the foo.c file and compile. If that works than you can be convinced it's a path problem (which I'm certain it is)

Comment: I should be able to include my library header file, right ? -- Owww ! I just did it ! Oh god thanks you for the help !!! It's kind of "messing up" (in fact, not at all) because of my folders structures. Since I'm not used to program in C, I tend to begin my projects in a "src" folder which contains all my sources. So, if I want to include my lib, I've to do "#include "../src/mylib.h".

Answer (score 0):

You should include

```
extern int foo();
```

in foo.c

then you can compile:

```
gcc -c mylib.c
gcc mylib.o foo.c -o foo
```

and execute:

```
./foo
```

As you are using eclipse, maybe it compiles corret after including the extern line and it's not needed to compile manually.